# Self Assessment from Abroad due to Private Limited Company Unpaid Directorship

Tags: united-kingdom, non-resident, private-company, self-assessment

I left the UK for good years ago, but I still have a private limited company there (that I own 100%) and because of that I have to file self assessment which is just a series of zeros in every input field because the private limited company is also not doing any business.

When filling out the self assessment, there is a question about whether I am a director of a private limited company or not (I am) and when I choose yes they ask for my P45/60 as provided by my private limited company to me. The problem is, I'm not on the payroll because I never paid myself a salary for being director and therefore there's no P45/P60 either so this leaves me with 2 options for filling out the personal self assessment AFAIK:

1. Just assume by "director" they mean a salaried employee and since that I am not, just claim that I am not a director of any company in the UK.
2. Just fill out a P45/P60 template with a bunch of zeros on it (truth) and provided that when filling out my personal self assessment.

Question: What is the correct course of action here?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just wind up the company if it's not doing any business?

Comment: @Vicky - a set-up company is a beautiful thing to lose.  they're almost always worth hanging on to.

Comment: @Vicky Exactly the same thoughts here as mentioned by Fattie. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Check 'No' and make a note explaining that there was no income from the directorship.

Longer version: After having paid a professional to do it for me I can confirm that what they ended up doing is ticking 'No' for directorship on the basis that I had no income from said directorship and then provided a free-form explanation stating that the reason why they ticked 'No' is as stated above.